# Limit Skydrive upload bandwidth in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive, qos

I've setup a new computer in the house with Windows 8.1 and have it syncing photos and music with Skydrive. The syncing works great, but it is taking days to get all the files uploaded and it is killing the performance off streaming videos, RDP, and any other network intensive application.

Is there a way to limit this using QoS? What would the correct settings be to keep skydrive as a lower priority but still let it use the bandwidth it needs when nothing else is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and failed to find a way to limit Skydrive directly. Apparently there was a setting in the old Skydrive app, but not in the integrated Skydrive solution for Windows 8.1.

I ended up using [Netbalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/), which lets you limit the bandwidth usage of any running program with right click => edit priority.

Netbalancer is free (just ignore the trial expiry warning, it is just for the advanced version).

Although Netbalancer works well, I personally don't want to have it running constantly. So now I only use my 200GB Skydrive to store backups which I upload once and then hopefully never touch again, for everything else I use Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, will give it a try. I solved the problem by removing every single thing from onedrive, and just being careful not to accidentally allow it to get hold of photos or videos when I process from my cameras. If it has nothing to sycn... it doesn't. And I turned off the feature allowing microsoft to use my bandwidth for their updates.  But storing backups is a good idea if I can cap it, as you suggest.

Comment: You describe what you did, but your post seems to indicate that you weren't entirely happy with the result.  That's not a glowing recommendation for your solution.  Can you clarify whether you're recommending your solution and what the shortcomings are?  If you aren't recommending it, an answer wouldn't be the appropriate type of post.  With a little more rep, you will be able to upvote answers you find useful or post a comment with a critique or useful supplementary information.